# Seeding my DB with Entity Framework DateTimes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am using Code First Workflow with Entity Framework 6.1.3 and I am trying to seed my database with some data by adding a migration like so:

```
public partial class SeedDatabaseWithBusinesses : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (GooglePlaceId, Name, CurrentMenu, LastUpdated)" +
            " VALUES ('googlePlaceIdHere', 'Examples Businesses Name', 'Fish and Chips, BLT, Chicken Sandwich', " + DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

}

But something is wrong with the way I am inputting the DateTime for the LastUpdated property which is of type DateTime. It is throwing an exception with SQL Server 2016 when I run update-database in NuGet which is saying "incorrect syntax." I know the DateTime is the problem because the exception message changes depending on what I do with the DateTime entry. **I have tried DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.ToString(), and DateTime.UtcNow which is what I found on another StackOverflow question that was similar but not the same.**

My LastUpdated value in my database is not nullable, so without this working, I cannot seed my database this way. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE - Added Model and DbContext:

---

```
public class Business
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string CurrentMenu { get; set; }
    }
```

---

DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post your Context/DataModel?

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes for the DateTime? Like "...Chicken Sandwich', '" + DateTime.UtcNow + "'"); Not sure but I'd give it a try.

Comment: Btw, my wild guess would be that you might need a `CAST` or `TO_DATE` (whichever you prefer) to convert the DateTime value to `Date` or `Timestamp` (whichever type you use on db column)

Comment: Why don't you use your model to insert data ?

Comment: met.lord tried that but it actually said that the entire date was still the wrong syntax.

@uteist Well the db column is of type 'datetime'. I updated with my context and model

Comment: Can you try this `Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (GooglePlaceId, Name, CurrentMenu, LastUpdated)" +
            " VALUES ('googlePlaceIdHere', 'Examples Businesses Name', 'Fish and Chips, BLT, Chicken Sandwich', TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") +"', 'YYYY/MM/DD'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert the current UTC datetime value, you can use `GETUTCDATE()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx). Your query would then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Businesses (GooglePlaceId, Name, CurrentMenu, LastUpdated)
VALUES ('googlePlaceIdHere', 'Examples Businesses Name', 'Fish and Chips', GETUTCDATE());
```

Alternatively, if you really really really want to do string concatenation with C# `DateTime.Now`, you could do this:

```
 Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (GooglePlaceId, Name, CurrentMenu, LastUpdated)" +
     " VALUES ('googlePlaceIdHere', 'Examples Businesses Name', 'Fish and Chips, BLT, Chicken Sandwich', " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"));
```